# No boot device has been detectede after minor update in 12.04

Tags: boot, updates, reboot

June 24, 2012. Minor update. As far as I remember about 20 objects, at least some related to virtual box.

Reboot next day gives Message:
No boot device has been detected, please press any key to reboot!

well,... that 'anykey' won't work.

No dualboot. Just have Ubuntu 12.04, 64bits version.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Boot from Ubuntu CD, and reinstall `grub`:

After booting, start a `Terminal`, and

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
```

After this, enter the following command:

`sudo chroot /mnt`

For install grub, enter the following command:

`sudo apt-get install-grub2`

Now update grub:

`sudo update-grub2`

Reboot.

Comment: Hi Frantique, thanks for your help. I made an boot CD with Ubuntu. After starting a terminal I can't mount /dev/sda1. This special device "Does not exist" when I boot from the CD.

Comment: Hi Frantique & LovinBuntu, Today I tried boot-repair.
Result-URL: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1087498/ Do I have to mount "/dev/sda" in stead of "/dev/sda1"? Thnx for your help,
Frank

Comment: Perhaps you should first check the HDD-s partitioning with `sudo  fdisk -l` after booting from the live CD. Let's see, what you have there.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. From a live-CD, run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)'s "Recommended repair",
2. Note the URL that will appear,
3. Reboot the PC.
4. If any problem, indicate the URL.